# Why did getline not reach the end of the file in C++?

Tags: c++, io

I have a simple function that edits an HTML file. All it does is just to replace some texts in the file. This is the code for the function:

```
void edit_file(char* data1, char* data1_token, char* data2, char* data2_token) {

    std::ifstream filein("datafile.html");
    std::ofstream fileout("temp.html");
    std::string line;

    //bool found = false;
    while(std::getline(filein, line))
    {
       std::size_t for_data1 = line.find(data1_token);
       std::size_t for_data2 = line.find(data2_token);
       if (for_data1 != std::string::npos) {
          line.replace(for_data1, 11, data1);
       }
       if (for_data2 != std::string::npos) {
          line.replace(for_data2, 19, data2);
       }
       fileout<<line;
    }
    filein.close();
    fileout.close();
}

void edit_file_and_copy_back(char* data1, char* data1_token, char* data2, char* data2_token)
{
    edit_file(data1, data1_token, data2, data2_token);
    MoveFileEx("temp.html", "datafile.html", MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

For some reasons, I will call this function multiple times, but this function only works for the first time, and later on the "getline" it will stop somewhere in the middle of the file.

The replace function works without any problems (because it works the first time). However, the second time, the `while` loop will end after just reading some lines.

I have tried filein.close() or file.seekg function, but neither of them fix the problem. What causes the incorrect execution and how do to solve it?

Comment: Are there any exceptions thrown during file reading? Can you paste the file contents here?

Comment: What is `write_back_file()`?  Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Please include *minimal* example input and output. Also, consider pasting the code for `write_back_file`, as that seems to affect the file objects? Lastly, a style note for your own coding: intermixing the use of `std::` and the omission of `std::` is bad. Either have `using namespace std` or don't, and stick with your decision. (I recommend not having it).

Comment: If you're on windows and you are trying to simultaneously read and write a file, you may end up accidentally locking it, preventing it from being modified.

Comment: Please note that [std::string::replace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) can throw exceptions.

Comment: There is nothing obvious in the function which would explain the behaviour.    The problem is either in the caller (e.g. some form of undefined behaviour) or in `write_back_file()`, neither of which you have shown.    One "joy" of undefined behaviour is that the symptom can occur in code completely unrelated to the cause.

Comment: Thank you for comments. I have edited and add the write_back_file() function. Replace function works without any problems (because it works at the first time). However, at the second time, while loop will end after just read some lines.

Comment: Your `write_back_file` function is called before your input or output streams are closed in `edit_file`.  Did you intend to reopen files that are already opened?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I've moved write_back_file function somewhere after edit_file function, but the result is unchanged.

Comment: @Saintycer Note that your code is still not a [mcve].  We don't know when, where, or how that `edit_file` function is called, what parameters are being passed, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buffering is biting you. Here's what you're doing:

1. Opening `datafile.html` for read and `temp.html` for write
2. Copying lines from `datafile.html` to `temp.html`
3. When you're done, without closing or flushing `temp.html`, you open a separate handle to `temp.html` for read (which won't share the buffer with the original handle, so unflushed data isn't seen)
4. You open a separate handle to `datafile.html` for write, and copying from the second `temp.html` handle to the new `datafile.html` handle

But the copy in steps 3 & 4 is missing the data still in the buffer for `temp.html` opened in step 1. And each time you call this, if the input and output buffer sizes don't match, or the `iostream` implementation you're using doesn't flush until you write buffer size + 1 bytes, you'll drop up to another buffer size worth of data.

Change your code so the scope of the original handles ends before you call the copy back function:

```
void edit_file(char* data1, char* data1_token, char* data2, char* data2_token) {
  {  // New scope; when it ends, files are closed
    ifstream filein("datafile.html");
    ofstream fileout("temp.html");
    string strTemp;
    std::string line;
     //bool found = false;
    while(std::getline(filein, line))
    {
       std::size_t for_data1 = line.find(data1_token);
       std::size_t for_data2 = line.find(data2_token);
       if (for_data1 != std::string::npos) {
          line.replace(for_data1, 11, data1);
       }
       if (for_data2 != std::string::npos) {
          line.replace(for_data2, 19, data2);
       }
       fileout<<line;
    }
  } // End of new scope, files closed at this point
  write_back_file();
}

void write_back_file() {
  ifstream filein("temp.html");
  ofstream fileout("datafile.html");
  fileout<<filein.rdbuf();
}
```

Mind you, this still has potential errors; if both data tokens are found, and `data1_token` occurs before `data2_token`, the index for `data2_token` will be stale when you use it; you need to delay the scan for `data2_token` until after you scan *and* replace `data1_token` (or if the `data1_token` replacement might create a `data2_token` that shouldn't be replaced, you'll need to compare the hit indices and perform the replacement for the later hit first, so the earlier index remains valid).

Similarly, from a performance and atomicity perspective, you probably don't want to *copy* from `temp.html` back to `datafile.html`; other threads and processes would be able to see the incomplete `datafile.html` in that case, rather than seeing the old version atomically replaced with the new version. It also means you need to worry about removing `temp.html` at some point. Typically, you just move the temporary file over the original file:

```
rename("temp.html", "datafile.html");
```

If you're on Windows, that won't work atomically to replace an existing file; you'd need to use [`MoveFileEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240(v=vs.85).aspx) to force replacing of existing files:

```
MoveFileEx("temp.html", "datafile.html", MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Comment: Really appreciate for pointing problems out. I've modified my code accordingly (please refer to the updated post). But I may need help with closing/flushing fstream file. When I googled it, I got an answer that "The file will be closed when fstream leaves the scope". Still, I force close the file by calling file.close(). However, it still didn't fix the original problem. Do you know what the appropriate way to close file before re-edit it?

Comment: @Saintycer: Letting it go out of scope, as I demonstrated, is the most reliable way to do it; explicit `close` calls can be bypassed by exceptions propagating, while scope based control guarantees cleanup (granted, an exception that propagates out of this function would also clean it up, and it would bypass the `write_back_file` call, so `datafile.html` would remain unchanged, only `temp.html` would be modified). If you used scope based cleanup correctly, this should behave correctly (aside from the other issues noted); if it doesn't, you've got other problems not visible from the example.

Answer (score 0):

```
void edit_file(char* data1, char* data1_token, char* data2, char* data2_token) {
  ifstream filein("datafile.html");
  ofstream fileout("temp.html");

  // STUFF

  // At this point the two streams are still open and
  // may not have been flushed to the file system.
  // You now call this function.
  write_back_file();
}

void write_back_file() {
  // You are opening files that are already open.
  // Do not think there are any guarantees about the content at this point.
  // So what is copied is questionable.
  ifstream filein("temp.html");
  ofstream fileout("datafile.html");
  fileout<<filein.rdbuf();
}
```

Do not call `write_back_file()` from within `edit_file()`. Rather provide a wrapper that calls both.

```
void edit_file_and_copy_back(char* data1, char* data1_token, char* data2, char* data2_token)
{
    edit_file(data1, data1_token, data2, data2_token);
    write_back_file();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have done the exactly the same thing :)